# How can I tell how full an Azure Storage account is?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is there any way of determining the used and/or remaining capacity of an Azure Storage account? I know that the current size limit is 100TB per storage account and I'm looking for either number of bytes used/remaining or, failing that, percentage used/remaining. However I can't see any way of monitoring this even in the Azure portal, let alone doing it programmatically via the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it's possible to get it in **Azure Monitor**. In Azure Portal navigate to *All services -> Monitor*, click *Expore Metrics* and select your storage account. There are different useful metrics and **Capacity** metric is among them.

Comment: Good find! Is there any way of accessing this information programmatically?

Answer (score 8):

You have to enable [Storage Analytics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343270.aspx). Then read about [Storage Account Monitoring](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitor-storage-account/). 
Finally a look at the [Analytics Metrics table(s)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343258.aspx). Note that it takes minimum 15 minutes until metrics are updated.

And btw, Azure Storage account limit is 500 TB as per [Azure Subscription and Service Limits](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/).

UPDATE

After reconsidering, the only way you can get the full storage capacity report is via the Account Billing page. Simply click on your name on top right (management portal v.Current, a.k.a. https://manage.windowsazure.com/) then chose "View My Bill" option.

This page is updated on a **daily** basis.

There is no API or other programmatic way to get these statistics.

Comment: As one of those web pages states: "Currently, capacity metrics are only available for the Blob service. Capacity metrics for the Table service and Queue service will be available in future versions of Storage Analytics". I need to know how full the *account* is, not just the size of the blobs in it. It seems as though this is not possible at present, would that be an accurate assumption?

Comment: @astaykov Is there a current equivalent to your last link?

Answer (score 2):

If you open the storage account in the Azure Portal, there is a Metrics tab (in the menu on the left, not a conventional tab) which will provide you with graphs on account utilisation including used capacity.

This tab works even without usage of Storage Analytics or the Azure Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Storage Metrics only stores capacity metrics for the blob service because blobs typically account for the largest proportion of stored data (at the time of writing, it is not possible to use Storage Metrics to monitor the capacity of your tables and queues). You can find this data in the $MetricsCapacityBlob table if you have enabled monitoring for the Blob service. Take a look at this [Monitoring Capacity](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting/#monitoring-capacity) document for information on how to monitor the capacity of your storage accounts.

For help estimating the size of various storage objects such as blobs, see the blog post Understanding Azure Storage Billing – Bandwidth, Transactions, and Capacity. [Understanding Storage Billing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx),

Note that Storage does have API's for access metric data programmatically using the CloudAnalyticsClient API. See [CloudAnalyticsAPI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/40c04ce1dbbc0c569316da0e3fe47b9bff5d3042/Test/ClassLibraryCommon/Analytics/CloudAnalyticsClientTests.cs) for a summary.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Actually in this case the link only answer is likely to be the most current. As our capacity metrics improve that article will be updated - StackOverflow will not be.

Comment: Your argument might be comprehensible, but your answer doesn't meet the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): _Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._

Comment: Updated based on feedback